# Hide FAB when onscreen keyboard appear

Tags: material-design, flutter, floating-action-button

In Flutter, how to make [FAB button](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html) hide when onscreen keyboard appear?

FAB button cover up other element when on screenkeyboard show up.

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Wrap your `FloatingActionButton` with a `Visibility` widget and control the visibility with a `bool` value.

Snippet:

```
Widget build(context) {
  bool keyboardIsOpen = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;
  return Scaffold(
    body: // ...
    floatingActionButton: Visibility(
      visible: !keyboardIsOpen,
      child: // your FloatingActionButton
    ),
  );
}
```

This solution also gets rid of the animation when the button disappears and appears.

Be sure that the class `extends StatefulWidget` and you have created a state for it

Comment: I would prefer this solution over the answered one

Comment: great solution, but no need for variable or StatefulWidget, simplify as... ```visible:MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0```

Comment: I implemented this in my project. Working only in two of the screens and the rest is not changing.

Answer (score 52):

You can achieve it by checking for keyboard visibility using [`viewInsets`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/viewInsets.html) and hide fab based on it.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: "Example",
    home: new FabHideOnKeyboard(),
  ));
}

class FabHideOnKeyboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FabHideOnKeyboardState createState() => new _FabHideOnKeyboardState();
}

class _FabHideOnKeyboardState extends State<FabHideOnKeyboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool showFab = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom==0.0;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
      body:Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("TextField:"),
            TextField()
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: showFab?Icon(Icons.add):null,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `MediaQuery.of(context)` will trigger the rebuild everytime when that value change and then it will trigger rebuild again... which end up in a loop ?

Comment: this causes the widget to rebuild.

Comment: @CharlesC, it will rebuild, and this is ok, even though if you don't use MediaQuery.of(context). Because when you trigger a focus, screen should rebuild.

Answer (score 9):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false)
```

Comment: Perfect for my use case.

Comment: a simple one liner

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, this is an implementation following the basic idea from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26100 but using already existing mixins to reduce quirks and code:

```
class FixedCenterDockedFabLocation extends StandardFabLocation
    with FabCenterOffsetX, FabDockedOffsetY {
  const FixedCenterDockedFabLocation();

  @override
  String toString() => 'FloatingActionButtonLocation.fixedCenterDocked';

  @override
  double getOffsetY(
      ScaffoldPrelayoutGeometry scaffoldGeometry, double adjustment) {
    final double contentBottom = scaffoldGeometry.contentBottom;
    final double bottomMinInset = scaffoldGeometry.minInsets.bottom;
    if (bottomMinInset > 0) {
      // Hide if there's a keyboard
      return contentBottom;
    }
    return super.getOffsetY(scaffoldGeometry, adjustment);
  }
}
```

You can then use it as simple as `floatingActionButtonLocation: const FixedCenterDockedFabLocation(),` (don't forget the const ;)).

Feel free to use this code without limitations or attribution.

Answer (score 2):

```
Widget build(context) {
  return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    appBar: // ...
    body: // ...
    floatingActionButton: Visibility(
      child: // your FloatingActionButton
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: i just added `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` in scaffold widget. It works for me to hide floating action button.

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(context) {


 bool iskeyboardOpen = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container()// ...
    floatingActionButton: Visibility(
      visible: !iskeyboardOpen,
      child: DashboardActionButton(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) {
                return const YourPage();
              })).then((_) {
                AsyncOrderActions(store).fetchData();
              });
            },
            svgIcon: 'send-white',
          ), // your FloatingActionButton
    ),
  );
}
```